# xml с xsl стилем не отображается в браузере Google Chrome

Tags: xml, браузер, xslt, xsl

У меня есть **xml файл:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='style1.xsl'?>

<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Бельгийские Вафли</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>
        две известных Бельгийских Вафли с обилием настоящего кленового сиропа
        </description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>cake</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>
        легкие Бельгийские вафли с земляникой, покрытые взбитыми сливками
        </description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Бельгийские Вафли с Ягодами</name>
        <price>$8.95</price>
        <description>
        легкие Бельгийские вафли с различными свежими ягодами, покрытые взбитыми сливками
        </description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Французский Тост</name>
        <price>$4.50</price>
        <description>
        толстые куски, сделанные из кусочков домашнего хлеба из опары
        </description>
        <calories>600</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Домашний Завтрак</name>
        <price>$6.95</price>
        <description>
        пара яиц, бекон или колбаса, тост, и наши всегда популярные картофельные оладьи
        </description>
        <calories>950</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

и **xsl файл:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Блюда</h2>

    <table border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
          <th>Название</th>
          <th>Цена</th>
          <th>Описание</th>
          <th>Калории</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="breakfast_menu/food">        
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="price"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="description"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="calories"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Если с помощью сайта, например, преобразовываю xml в html - то всё работает. Но без преобразования, при открытии xml файла открывается пустая страница в гугле.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему так и как исправить?**

Comment: У меня всё работает.  Убедитесь, что *XSLT* доступен по нужному адресу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашёл причину ошибки. Это всё меры защиты хрома. Он не позволяет открыть таблицу стилей из xml. В разных браузерах это то работает, то - нет.

Вот как сделать что бы работало в хроме:

> You can do this locally using Chrome's command line flags.
>
> The specific flag is --allow-file-access-from-files
>
> On OS X: from Terminal.app run /Applications/Google\
>   Chrome.app/contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
>   --allow-file-access-from-files
>
> On Windows: from the command prompt run
>   %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
>   --allow-file-access-from-files
>
> Note: You will probably have to quit Chrome if it is currently running otherwise Ch

Ссылка на обсуждение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828898/can-chrome-be-made-to-perform-an-xsl-transform-on-a-local-file